# Clickonce - How to check for updates in another directory than originally published

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

We have a Visual Basic application that is configured to use ClickOnce for its publishing. Right now the developpers publish new versions of the application on the  network, (in a directory where they have write permissions) and the clients get the updated versions when opening the .application file. So far so good.

Now, due to new security measures, the updates shouldnot come anymore from the network where developpers have write permissions, but instead from a protected directory where the developpers only have read permissions. This is to prevent publishing in the destination folder by mistake without passing by the QA and UAT process.

Is there a way to still publish new versions on the network where they have write permissions, and then ask a sysadmin to copy that new version to the protected read-only folder? If so, what should be modified/configured for the clients using the application to check the protected folder for updates instead of the write folder where the application was originally published by the developpers?

Or is there any other way of publishing to a directory where the developpers don't have 
write permissions?

I hope my question is clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to change this is modifying the manifests using a text editor and then re-sign them, to do this you can use [mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx)!

You could publish it to an intermediate folder using the final/production folder/URL and then ask the sys admin to create a copy of it for QA and UAT, modify the manifests and sign them to point to the TEST folder and once QA and UAT passed the sys admin can copy the original files without changes to the production folder.